# Телеграм бот: ошибка aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, python-3.6

Не знаю как правильно объяснить, но попробую, если что в коде думаю всё будет понятно, добавил одну инлайн клавиатуру всё работало хорошо, но потом добавил ещё и другую инлайн клавиатуру и после этого выходит ошибка aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object. Попытался найти решение, но всё тщетно. Помогите пожалуйста с решением данной проблемы.

Код состоит из 3 файлов
1 файл main

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from Buttons import kb, ikb, ikkb, good
from text import TEXT

BOT_TOKEN = "TOKEN"

bot = Bot(BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_message(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("<b>Добро пожаловать в наш магазин!</b>",
                         parse_mode="HTML")
    await bot.send_sticker(message.from_user.id,
                           sticker="CAACAgIAAxkBAAEGENdjRqYnLj0GfoaH3ShZmgKbpoe0OwACBQADwDZPE_lqX5qCa011KgQ",
                           reply_markup=kb)
    await message.delete()


@dp.message_handler()
async def handlers(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "Товары":
        await message.answer(TEXT,
                             parse_mode="HTML")
    elif message.text == "❤Поддержка❤":
        await message.answer("Поддержка - Ник нэйм")
    elif message.text == "Купить":
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                               text="Активные категории в магазине:",
                               reply_markup=ikb)


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def ikb(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback.data == "Дубай":
        await callback.message.answer("<b> Товар:</b>Cavallo| Дубай"
                                      "\n <b>Цена: 1200₽</b>"
                                      "\n <b>Описание</b>: Похожи на Winston XStyle, компакт, кент"
                                      "\n\nВыберите количество товара, которое хотите купить:",
                                      parse_mode="HTML",
                                      reply_markup=ikkb)
        await callback.answer()


@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def ikkb(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    if callback.data == "one":
        await callback.message.answer("Вы уверены, что хотите оплатить заказ?",
                                      reply_markup=good)
        await callback.answer()


async def on_startup(_):
    print("Бот успешно запущен!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp,
                           skip_updates=False,
                           on_startup=on_startup)
```

2 файл Buttons

```
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
b1 = KeyboardButton("Купить")
b2 = KeyboardButton("❤Поддержка❤")
b3 = KeyboardButton("Товары")
b4 = KeyboardButton("Профиль")
kb.add(b1).insert(b3).add(b4).insert(b2)

ikb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
ik = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Cavallo| Дубай",
                          callback_data="Дубай")
ik2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Cavallo Twin&Ball",
                           callback_data="Twin&Ball")
ik3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Manchester Chocolate",
                           callback_data="Manchester")
ik4 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="MILANO",
                           callback_data="MILANO")
ik5 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Boston",
                           callback_data="Boston")
ik6 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Winston compact",
                           callback_data="Winston")
ikb.add(ik).insert(ik2).add(ik3).insert(ik4).add(ik5).insert(ik6)

ikkb = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
ib = InlineKeyboardButton(text="1",
                          callback_data="one")
ib2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="2",
                           callback_data="two")
ib3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="3",
                           callback_data="three")
ib4 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="4",
                           callback_data="four")
ib5 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="5",
                           callback_data="five")
ib6 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Назад к категориям",
                           callback_data="all")
ikkb.insert(ib).insert(ib2).insert(ib3).insert(ib4).insert(ib5).add(ib6)

good = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
ib1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="✅Подтверждаю✅",
                           callback_data="yes")
ib22 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="Отмена",
                            callback_data="no")
good.add(ib).add(ib2)
```

3 файл не важен, так как там просто текст, то есть описание товаров.

Вот полная ошибка

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-8' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest("Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 29, in handlers
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 341, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\C0sMiX\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Can't parse reply keyboard markup json object
```

Answer (score 0):

Напиши в твоём файле "Buttons"
вместо
`ikb.add(ik).insert(ik2).add(ik3).insert(ik4).add(ik5).insert(ik6)`

```
ikb.add(ik)
ikb.insert(ik2)
ikb.add(ik3)
ikb.insert(ik4)
ikb.add(ik5)
ikb.insert(ik6)
```